# redirect after registration is not working

Tags: php

I can't figure out why my redirection wont work? 
All I get is a blank page with the same url from where I tried to redirect from..
The code is from my registration page, however I removed some code to make it easier to look at my redirection here. Everything else is working except the redirection.

```
  <?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

 //removed bunch of code for clear overview for stackoverflow question
 // Prepare an insert statement

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";



        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);



            // Set parameters

            $param_username = $username;

            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash



            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
              // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
            } else{

                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";

            }

        }



        // Close statement

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    }



    // Close connection

    mysqli_close($link);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your redirect might work if you are going to this page.
Yo get a blank page because your code starts with:

`if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){`

You state that you have removed some code. If the code you expect to run is also in that codeblock and it is no `POST` (this might be a `GET`), the code inside that codeblock will not be executed.

There is no form tag in your example, but you could also check if you use `method="POST"`.

Comment: The code is from my registration.php. After this has been excuted by hitting my submit button, I want to navigate over to my login.php page. 

If I understood you correctly, my login.php page has something on it that messes with my redirection?

Comment: What does your form tag look like? Do you set method="POST"?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">